# Rtf file export leaves a first line blank

Tags: php, rtf

I am just trying to make **.rtf** file with simple following content ("eee"). When i open my file it has added one blank line before my output.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test.rtf");
    echo 'eee'; die;
```

I also tried with

```
header("Content-type: application/rtf; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test.rtf");
echo 'eee'; die;
```

But still getting blank line added before output.

When I am trying to save as **.txt** file it's not adding any blank line.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test.txt");
echo 'eee'; die;
```

Comment: Do you have an empty line before '<?php'?

Comment: No I dont have.

Comment: @MrTux Hi you were right. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important that you don't have empty lines before `<?php` at the beginning of a line or at some other files which are included (e.g., after `?>`).

Answer (score 0):

I was using codeigniter framework. On controller I have loaded a model which had blank lines after **?> closing tag**. After deleting that It works fine. The reason why simple echo of text added blank space before output is RTF file viewer were expecting appropriate **content encoding** to be mentioned at the first line itself. So the output should commence like **{\rtf1\ansi}** this. Make sure no other texts or spaces inserted before.

Answer (score 0):

I was using

```
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    ...
    if ($isDownload) {
      header("Content-type: text/rtf;  charset=UTF-8");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.rtf");
      header("Expires: 0");
    }
    echo $rtf;
```

I fixed it by

```
    ob_start();
    ...
    if ($isDownload) {
      ob_clean()
      header("Content-type: text/rtf;  charset=UTF-8");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.rtf");
      header("Expires: 0");
    }
    echo $rtf;
```